# Component styles are not bundling in Angular 4

Tags: css, angularjs, webpack

In my component I have

```
styles: [require('./hero.component.css')],
```

And when I build the application

```
ng build --prod
```

The styles in that file are not getting in the bundle. Also I can't see the styles running the compiled application.

I also tried

```
styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
```

Which works in the compiled application, but it does not bundle the styles, instead it adds inline.

Is there a way to bundle component styles and make it work when building in production?

(The application was created with `ng new proj`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a [reply on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18097#issuecomment-315173626)

> This works as intended.
>
> If you specify the styles as part of the component then the styles get prefixed with component specific selector and will be inlined into the generated code. This is done intentionally to allow you to have style isolation as well as ability to code split your style-sheets along with your code for more optimal lazy-loading.

So apparently it is not possible to bundle with the generated project, you would need a custom webpack to bundle.

Also using this

```
styles: [require('./hero.component.css')],
```

Seems to be a bit dangerous since it works on development, but is not generated on `ng build --prod`. Using `styleUrls` works in production as well.